# Protractor + Chai

Tags: protractor, chai

In my Chai test, I have the following:

```
this.When(/^I click the (.*) button$/, function(button, next) {
    element(by.xpath('//input[@value="Log Out"]')).click();
    next();
});
```

#### I'm expecting this to FAIL because the text of my button is actually *Log in*

However, my test runs (before the browser is even displayed) and on the terminal I see:

```
Feature: Authentication
    In order to protect the system
    As an owner
    I want to require authentication

Scenario: Require username      features\general\authentication.feature:6
    Given I am on the login page        ...
    When I do not enter a username      ...
    And I click the "Log in" button     ...
    Then I should receive a validation error "The Username field is required." 

Scenario: Require password
    Given I am on the login page        ...
    When I do not enter a password      ...
    And I click the "Log in" button     ...
    Then I should receive a validation error "The Password field is required."

2 scenarios (2 passed)
8 steps (8 passed)
0m00.014s
```

Then, I finally see the browser open and the tests start going through the browser.

At this point, I receive the error:

```
C:\Projects\NexusWeb\Develop\Nexus.Web\Nexus.Web.Tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath("//input[@value=\"Log Out\"]")
```

This, of course is what I expect.

My questions...

1. Why do I receive a report that 2 scenarios passed, when the browser has not even stepped through them yet?
2. Why are they reporting passing when they both should fail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so, i figured it out...documentation is very scarce...

I needed to add a promise to click():

```
this.When(/^I click the (.*) button$/, function(button, next) {
    element(by.xpath('//input[@value="Log Out"]')).click().then(function() {
        next();
    });
});
```